# My Ctrl and D keys work, but Ctrl+D fails

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, freeze

My <kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys work perfectly fine individually, but the combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> doesn't respond in any program. My only theory about the problem is that a program running in the background is restricting its use somehow. I'm using Windows Vista.

How can I determine whether a program is reserving a key combination (if that's even possible)? More to the point, how can I make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> work?

Comment: Which OS? I'm presuming Windows XP/Vista/7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Active hot keys](http://www.donationcoder.com/Forums/bb/index.php?topic=18189.msg162881) will show you if the key combo is in effect, but not what it is used by. This question at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829007/find-out-what-process-registered-a-global-hotkey-windows-api) shows that it seems pretty tricky to find out.

Comment: Ok, so ActiveHotkeys shows that it is in fact set as a global hotkey. Hopefully it will be easy to disable it.

Comment: The link is currently broken

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you using?  Have you also tried any different keyboards?  There are things which can mess with key bindings, but it's rarer that some process is somehow stealing or intercepting your keystrokes than just some keyboard failure.  [This program](http://www.autohotkey.com/)  works on Windows and will help you gain more information about what's happening in your system if it is Windows-based.  If there is something intercepting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> system wide, it could be some sort of rootkit, but first see what something like autohotkey or similar turns up.

Comment: Thanks, I installed the program but I'm unsure how to get it to display what you're suggesting. Any help?

Comment: Okay, so AutoHotkey accepts control-D fine as a hotkey for running a script, which is strange because none of the other programs on my computer work, such as Firefox or any game where you crouch and try to move right.