# (Vista) Discover what app is reserving a shortcut key?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, keyboard-shortcuts, hook

My problem is this: I've always managed to map WIN+V to foobar2000's "Next song" keyboard shortcut.

For some reason, on this new machine, I can't.  I've done this before on Vista, so the only thing I can think of is that some other application is holding onto this shortcut key.

When I try to assign the shortcut key in foobar2000, nothing registers.  When I press it outside of foobar2000, nothing occurs either.

I'm at a loss as to how to proceed.  Are there any apps to see what hooks are being requested by what application?  Or is there a better way of diagnosing this?

Comment: Related question http://superuser.com/questions/87405/key-combination-not-working/87419#87419

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Windows Hotkey Explorer Free](http://hkcmdr.anymania.com/) will do what you want. It's a free hotkey utility that lists all hotkeys registered by Windows applications. You can run it just by clicking the exe without installing.

[image]

Comment: Note: Run this when you can walk away from the computer for a little while.  It seems to detect all the hotkeys on your system by _actually pressing all the hotkeys_ for you, then watching their effects.  Look for a Magnifying Glass overlay if everything looks twice as big by the time it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Hotkey Commander](http://hkcmdr.anymania.com/) - "Ultimate Hotkey Managing and Overriding Utility" (their description). There's a 15-day trial version, and a less-featured free version.